# Safe to delete/clear log file

Tags: jenkins

Just checking why my Jenkins builds have been failing and it seems that 
the main jenkins.log file has swallowed all available space on my drive. Would it be safe to remove this file (would jenkins create another) then i could change logging settings. 
Or is there information needed within this file on jobs/pipelines?

Sorry for noob question
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally safe to delete jenkins.log file. Jenkins doesn't read any information from log file.

When you delete the file, jenkins will create a new file when writing the new logs.

Comment: is there a way to disable this file as it get larger and I have to delete it manually everytime

Comment: AFAIK, There is no option in Jenkins to manage that log file. You can use a tool like logrotate to manage that log file.